# How to get value of a selected radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` with radioboxes:

```
<div id='RB-01'>
<span>Item_1</span><input type='radio' name='RB01' value='1'><br />
<span>Item_2</span><input type='radio' name='RB01' value='2'><br />
<span>Item_3</span><input type='radio' name='RB01' value='3'><br />
</div>
```

Then with `jQuery` I want to get number on an account a radiobox that was checked:

```
var obj;
var tempId = "RB-01";
if ($('div[id=' + tempId + ']')) {
  $('div[id=' + tempId + '] input').each(function() {

  ...here I need save in the variable obj the number on an account input that was checked... 

  }); 
}
```

Comment: @PabloFernandez: your code won't pass jslint you need to use `===`

Comment: @qwertymk so true. But as Brendan Eich himself said: "jslint can suck it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need

```
  $('div[id=' + tempId + '] input:checked').each(function() {

  var number = $(this).val();

  });
```

You could have quite easily found this on the jQuery API site...

[JQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)!

Comment: Actually he wants the radio input that is checked.  So this doesn't work.

Comment: I've edited my answer to suit - looks like I edited as as you wrote your comment!

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = null;
var tempId = "RB-01";

if ($('div[id=' + tempId + ']')) {
  obj = $('#' + tempId + ' input:checked').val();
}
```

There's no need to use the `div[id=RB-01]` selector since IDs are unique. Just use `#RB-01`. Then use the `:checked` selector to get the checked radio button.

Comment: yep no need for the loop just grab the checked radio.

Comment: `$('div[id=' + tempId + ']')` will always be true! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = null,
    tempId = "RB-01",
    $div = $('#'+tempId);

if ($div.length){
    obj = $div.find('input:radio:checked').val();
}
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/sSCCS/)